# How to modify the return value of CPUID of windows created by KVM

Tags: kvm, cpuid

I create a windows 7 x86 virtual machine by KVM.
When it executes the following instructions:

```c
mov eax, 0x40000000
cpuid
```

It will return this:

```
eax=0x40000005
ebx=0x7263694d
ecx=0x666f736f
edx=0x76482074
```

That is "Microsoft Hv".

How to adjust KVM to return custom value?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean QEMU/KVM, then you need to convince the hyperv enlightenments to have a different configuration.

- For the QEMU cli, use hv-vendor-id=foobarbaz as a flag. See [the docs](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/master/docs/hyperv.txt) for more.
- For libvirt: add `<vendor_id state='on' value='foobarbaz'/>` between the `<hyperv>` `</hyperv>` tags.

One lazy alternative is to disable the enlightenments across the board (which will hide the hyperv cpuid leaf).

*The following is probably not relevant, but it is a direct answer to this question.*
For a custom VMM that is directly using KVM, use the kvm_set_cpuid2 ioctl. Check out the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/virt/kvm/index.html) for more.

Comment: The qemu docs have moved. You can find the last published hyperv docs at https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/stable-6.1/docs/hyperv.txt . The master copy now lives at https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/master/docs/system/i386/hyperv.rst . Worthy of note: just setting vendor_id (and no other HyperV flags) does not enable enlightenments; it just changes the virtual CPU id.